# Python Install Modules of Multiple versions - Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am trying to install pandas to a second version of python I have 3.6.4 ( it works great on 3.6.6) and I am doing the code below in cmd line (windows):

```
py -3.6.4 -m pip install pandas
```

it is returning this:

```
Unknown option: -.
usage: C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file |
-] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.
```

So I input 'python -h' and got this chunk of message I just don't understand. i am just trying to install my modules to a different version of python and it is proving to be quite hard.

```
C:\Users\******\Python364>python -h
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Options and arguments (and corresponding environment variables):
-b     : issue warnings about str(bytes_instance), str(bytearray_instance)
         and comparing bytes/bytearray with str. (-bb: issue errors)
-B     : don't write .pyc files on import; also PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=x
-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)
-d     : debug output from parser; also PYTHONDEBUG=x
-E     : ignore PYTHON* environment variables (such as PYTHONPATH)
-h     : print this help message and exit (also --help)
-i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
         if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
-I     : isolate Python from the user's environment (implies -E and -s)
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
-O     : remove assert and __debug__-dependent statements; add .opt-1 before
         .pyc extension; also PYTHONOPTIMIZE=x
-OO    : do -O changes and also discard docstrings; add .opt-2 before
         .pyc extension
-q     : don't print version and copyright messages on interactive startup
-s     : don't add user site directory to sys.path; also PYTHONNOUSERSITE
-S     : don't imply 'import site' on initialization
-u     : force the binary I/O layers of stdout and stderr to be unbuffered;
         stdin is always buffered; text I/O layer will be line-buffered;
         also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
-v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x
         can be supplied multiple times to increase verbosity
-V     : print the Python version number and exit (also --version)
         when given twice, print more information about the build
-W arg : warning control; arg is action:message:category:module:lineno
         also PYTHONWARNINGS=arg
-x     : skip first line of source, allowing use of non-Unix forms of #!cmd
-X opt : set implementation-specific option
file   : program read from script file
-      : program read from stdin (default; interactive mode if a tty)
arg ...: arguments passed to program in sys.argv[1:]

Other environment variables:
PYTHONSTARTUP: file executed on interactive startup (no default)
PYTHONPATH   : ';'-separated list of directories prefixed to the
               default module search path.  The result is sys.path.
PYTHONHOME   : alternate <prefix> directory (or <prefix>;<exec_prefix>).
               The default module search path uses <prefix>\python{major}{min
.
PYTHONCASEOK : ignore case in 'import' statements (Windows).
PYTHONIOENCODING: Encoding[:errors] used for stdin/stdout/stderr.
PYTHONFAULTHANDLER: dump the Python traceback on fatal errors.
PYTHONHASHSEED: if this variable is set to 'random', a random value is used
   to seed the hashes of str, bytes and datetime objects.  It can also be
   set to an integer in the range [0,4294967295] to get hash values with a
   predictable seed.
PYTHONMALLOC: set the Python memory allocators and/or install debug hooks
   on Python memory allocators. Use PYTHONMALLOC=debug to install debug
   hooks.
```

Comment: Looks like you can only select the major version.

Comment: Have you tried using anaconda?

Comment: @mad physicist - so what does that mean (response to your first post) regarding you second question - yes I have anaconda, which downloaded 3.6.6. and works great. I need a different version of python (3.6.4) because I am making a .exe file via 'pyinstaller' and it only works python 3.6.4 for pandas scripts

Comment: You can select the exact version of python when you create an environment with conda

Comment: @ mad physicist I solved it. “Where python “ then specify python.exe -m Pip install pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can only select the major version, installing for 3.6 **should** work for both 3.6.6 and 3.6.4.

Comment: it does not, when I run scripts out of 3.6.4 it says "module not found" , I need to have it work in 3.6.4 so I can use pyinstaller to create an executable

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have two installations of python - 3.6.4 and 3.6.6. To install a new module to Python 3.6.4, you need to first activate that environment. You can do that by navigating to the installation path. And running the activate script by navigating to the scripts folder:

```
[Env-path]\Scripts\activate
```

Once you have activated the environment. You can install pandas there.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\patrick\anaconda3\lib\site-pac
kages (0.23.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\users\patrick\anaconda3\lib\sit
e-packages (from pandas) (2018.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in c:\users\patrick\anacon
da3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in c:\users\patrick\anaconda3\lib\si
te-packages (from pandas) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\patrick\anaconda3\lib\site-p
ackages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.11.0)

Comment: It looks like pandas is already installed in this environment. Do you want to install it in a different environment?

Comment: Thie above is what I get, the thing is I know I already met this requirement, and it is showing me it is downloaded in anaconda, but I am running that command in my newly activated path--(base) C:\Users\Patrick\Python364\Python36\Tools\scripts>, which now says root and is not the same as the path above ( which is where python 3.6.6 lives and I know pandas works there)

Comment: Try running your pandas script from this newly activated(I'm assuming this is the 3.6.4) environment. Pandas is already installed here and so it should work. Post the error you're getting while running that script.

Comment: yes I need to install it in an environment where python 3.6.4 lives in order to wrap it in a Pyinstaller executable

Comment: @ Shashank Verma

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Python364\Python36\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' @Shashank Verma - that is the error in IDLE, I my script is just import pandas

Comment: Are you activating the 3.6.4 environment before running your script? Do a python --version from where you ran your test script. It'll show the python version(environment) IDLE is currently using.

Comment: I did a "where python" then I input that path and from there I did pip install pandas and now it Works!!! @ Shashank Verma thank you for your help

Comment: Cool. That's great.